# Добавление случайных чисел в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа, push

есть класс в котором генерируется таблица с ячейками
Нужно в эту таблицу добавлять случайные числа от 0  до 9 включительно с помощью рандомной ф-ции

```js
class Sudoku{
     // шаг 19 добавм 81 0
    constructor (initString = '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
        // шаг 20 превратим в массив
        const  startValue = initString
            .split('')
            .filter(x => '0123456789'.includes(x))
            // шаг 21 превратим в цифры 
            .map(x => Number(x))
            console.log(startValue);

        this.body = [];

        // Зададим порядковый номер ячейки
        let idCounter = 1;
        // пройдемся по строкам
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            // пройдемся по столбцам
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                this.body.push({
                    id: idCounter,
                    x:x,
                    y:y,
                    number: startValue[idCounter -1], // отнимаем чтобы взять первую ячейку п позиции 0 
                    // шаг 9 добавим классы для ячеек с фоуком и без
                    selected: false,
                    supported: false,
                    // шаг 27 добавим поле не важно 
                    important: false,
                    // шаг 35
                    error: false,
                    // шаг 24  поле начала ячейки - является ли это поле началом ? startValue[idCounter -1]
                    started: startValue[idCounter -1] === 0 ? false : true,
                    s: parseInt(y / 3) * 3 + parseInt(x / 3)
                });

                idCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Создадим ф-ции быстрого доступа к ячейкам и строка
    getRow(n){
        const row = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){ // у нас 9 строк
            row.push(this.body[9 * n + i]); // находим все эленты строки с номером n
        }

        return row;

    }

    getColum(n){
        const column = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            column.push(this.body[i * 9 + n]); // находим все эленты колонки с номером n
        }

        return column;

    }

    getSegment(n){
        const segment = [];

        // находми координаты x нашего сегмента
        const x = n % 3;
        // находми координаты y нашего сегмента
        const y = parseInt(n / 3);

        // пройдемся 3 раза по ячейкам сегметна dx dy - отклонения от наших ячеек внутри сегмента
        for (let dy = 0; dy < 3; dy++) {
            for (let dx = 0; dx < 3; dx++) {
                segment.push(this.body[
                    y * 27 + dy * 9 + x * 3 + dx
                ]);
                
            }
            
        }
        return segment;
    }

    // шаг 8 создаем ф-ции keydownHandler focusHandler blurHandler
    keydownHandler(event, cell){
        // шаг 26 проверим если ячейка не started
        if(!cell.started){
            // шаг 15 - сделаем так что бы можно было вводить только один символ цифру!
            // console.log(event.key)
            //  сравниваем если это не одно из чисел
            if("0123456789".includes(event.key)){
                cell.number = parseInt(event.key)

                // шаг 38 удалим error со всх ячеек
                if(cell.error){
                    for(const item of this.body){
                        item.error = false
                    }
                }

                // шаг 34 сделаем невозможным повтор одинаковых цифр в одном сегменте
                // добавим в свойствах объекта error
                //  пройдем по строкам
                for(const item of this.getRow(cell.y)){
                    if(item === cell){
                        continue
                    }

                    if(item.number === cell.number){
                        item.error = true
                        cell.error = true
                    }
                }
                //  тожу самое для ячеек
                for(const item of this.getColum(cell.x)){
                    if(item === cell){
                        continue
                    }

                    if(item.number === cell.number){
                        item.error = true
                        cell.error = true
                    }
                }

                //  тожу самое для сегмента
                for(const item of this.getSegment(cell.s)){
                    if(item === cell){
                        continue
                    }

                    if(item.number === cell.number){
                        item.error = true
                        cell.error = true
                    }
                }
            }

            // шаг 23 добавм возможность удалять цифры
            else if(["Backspace", "Delete"].includes(event.key)){
                cell.number = 0

                // шаг 28 пройдемся по всем ячейкам и уберем important
                for(const item of this.body){
                    item.important = false
                }

                if(cell.number){
                    for(const item of this.body){
                        // если совпадает то делаем true
                        if(item.number === cell.number){
                            item.important = true
                        }
                        
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        // console.log("keydownHandler", event, cell)

        
        event.preventDefault() // отменяет все дейсвия
        this.veiwUpdate()
    }
    focusHandler(event, cell){
        // console.log("focusHandler", event, cell)
        cell.selected = true
        // шаг 11 проходим по всем срокам 
        for(const item of this.getRow(cell.y)){
            item.supported = true
        }

        // шаг 12 проходим по всем колонкам
        for(const item of this.getColum(cell.x)){
            item.supported = true
        }

         // шаг 33 проходим по всем ячейкам
         if(cell.number){
             for(const item of this.body){
                if(item.number === cell.number){
                    item.important = true
                }
             }
         }

        this.veiwUpdate();
    }

    blurHandler(event, cell){
        // console.log("blurHandler", event, cell)
         // шаг 14 ставим false
         cell.selected = false
        
        // шаг 32 так как мы проходим по всем ячейкам можно удалить два цикла for
        // for(const item of this.getRow(cell.y)){
        //     item.supported = false
        // }

        // for(const item of this.getColum(cell.x)){
        //     item.supported = false
        // }

         // шаг 37 удалим error полсе снятия фокуса
        if(cell.error){
            cell.number = 0
        }

         // шаг 31 обходим все ячейки
         for(const cell of this.body){
             cell.important = false
             cell.supported = false
             cell.error = false
         }
        


        this.veiwUpdate();
    }


    // Создадим структуру html doc
    getHTML(size){  // размер нашего поля

        // шаг 6 создадим инпуты
        // item - элемент массива
        for(const item of this.body){
            const imputElement = document.createElement('input');
            imputElement.classList.add("sudoku-cell");
            imputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');

            // шаг 7 прослушаем нашу ячейку
            //  нам нежен keydown focus blur 
            imputElement.addEventListener('keydown', event => this.keydownHandler(event, item))
            imputElement.addEventListener('focus', event => this.focusHandler(event, item))
            imputElement.addEventListener('blur', event => this.blurHandler(event, item))

             // шаг 25 проверим если ячейка started добавляем класс
             if(item.started){
                imputElement.classList.add("start-cell")
             }



            item.element = imputElement;
        }

        const rootElement = document.createElement('div');
        rootElement.classList.add("sudoku-game");
        // Добавим высоту ширину и размер шрифта
        rootElement.style.width = `${size}px`
        rootElement.style.height = `${size}px`
        rootElement.style["font-size"] = `${size / 20}px`

        // шаг 4 создаем 9 сегментов 
        for (let s = 0; s < 9; s++) {
            const segmentElement = document.createElement('div')
            segmentElement.classList.add("sudoku-segment")

            // шаг 6 пройдемся по ячейкам сегметна
            // cell - клетка судоку
            for(const cell of this.getSegment(s)){
                segmentElement.append(cell.element)
            }

            rootElement.append(segmentElement);
            
        }
        // шаг 22 отобразим содержимое ячеек содержимое
        this.veiwUpdate(); 

        return rootElement;
    }

    veiwUpdate(){
        // шаг 13 проходим по всем ячейкам
        for(const cell of this.body){
            // шаг 30 удалим класс important-cell у всех ячеек
            // шаг 35 удалим класс error
            cell.element.classList.remove("error", "important-cell", "supported-cell", "selected-cell")
            // шаг 16 
            cell.element.value = cell.number ? cell.number : ''
           

            // добавим условия елси ячейка supported
            if(cell.supported){
                cell.element.classList.add("supported-cell")
            }

            if(cell.selected){
                cell.element.classList.add("selected-cell")
            }

             // шаг 29 добавим класс 
            if(cell.important){
                 cell.element.classList.add("important-cell")
             }

              // шаг 36
            if(cell.error){
                cell.element.classList.add("error")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Рандомная функция

```js
function getRandom(min, max){
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);

            return Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;

        }

        console.log( getRandom(0, 10) );
```

файл в котором вызывается класс

```js
const sudoku = new Sudoku(`
    5 0 3  0 0 4  6 7 0 
    0 9 0  2 5 0  8 3 1
    0 0 2  6 0 3  0 0 9
    0 2 0  3 7 0  0 1 5 
    0 0 8  0 2 0  7 6 0
    3 0 0  5 6 0  0 0 0
    4 6 0  0 0 0  1 0 7 
    2 8 1  0 4 0  0 0 0
    0 0 5  0 9 0  0 8 0
`)

document
    .querySelector('#app')
    .append(sudoku.getHTML(750)); // 500
```

=============================
задача 
1. запушить в массив целые числа от 0 до 9 
Заполнить массив числами на 50% на 30% и на 75%
как это правильно сделать? у кого какие идеии )) 
Спасибо заранее

Comment: "целые числа от 0 до 9 на 50% на 30% и на 75%" - ??

Comment: Добрый вечер поправил вопрос)

Comment: "Заполнить массив числами на 50% на 30% и на 75%" - я не понимаю, что это значит.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно заполнить массив на 30%, 50%, 75% etc. числами отличными от нуля? Если да, то предлагаю такой вариант: Сначала заполняешь массив числами отличными от нуля, после этого заменяешь нужное количество значений на нули.

```
function zeroFill (arr, percent) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ) >= percent) {
            return 0;
        }
        return item;
    });
}
```

ну и собственно вызываешь функцию, где первый аргумент твой массив с числами, а второй процент заполненности массива числами отличными от нуля. В функцию рандомного получения числа для массива, в параметр `min` передаешь число `1` , а не `0`;

Comment: Добрый день Vladimir, да все верно нужно заполнить массив в котором 81 ячейка, в зависимости от условия заполнить от  0 до 9 включительно 
Условие первое - заполнить на 30% 
Условие второе - заполнить на 50% 
Условие третье - заполнить на 75%

Comment: Попробуй вариант, который я предложил, думаю взлетит